# Hibernate doesn't log anything anymore, since I relocated the log4j.xml and hibernate.properties files

Tags: java, hibernate, log4j

I had the following working organization

- `src/main/resources/log4j.xml`
- `src/main/resources/hibernate.properties`

I wanted to reorganize my webapp as follow:

- `src/main/resources/log/log4j.xml`
- `src/main/resources/orm/hibernate.properties`

The `Logger.info("foobar")` still logs well (after having set the `log4jConfigLocation` context parameter), and the app still has a working database connection.

The problem is that Hibernate doesn't log anything anymore, even if `hibernate.show_sql` is set to `true`. Any idea why? Should specify the new path to the `log4j.xml` file to Hibernate? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run your server with this VM argument:-

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=/path/to/log4j.xml
```

I usually tend to place the log4j.xml at the recommended default location unless there's a need to do otherwise... "convention over configuration" is important especially if other peers may be working on the same project in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Log4j first looks for its configuration by looking at the system property "log4j.configuration". If that system property is not set, it looks for a log4j.properties or a log4j.xml file on the classpath.

So, if you really want the log4j.xml at src/main/resources/log/log4j.xml, you will have to set the log4j configuration system property. This is basically what limc does by supplying it as a vm argument.

Also like limc says, you should probably just keep the log4j.xml at the default location.